# Can I use the Visual Studio 2010 remote debugger on Windows XP to debug a .Net 4.0 app from Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-xp, remote-debugging

Can I use the Visual Studio 2010 remote debugger on Windows XP to debug a .Net 4.0 app from Visual Studio 2012?

I am trying to, here is a screenshot of my XP machine (I have disabled the local firewall temporarily):

[image: XP]

Here is Visual Studio 2012 (the text in the remote machine box is identical to the server name indictaed by the Visual Studio remote debugger):

[image: VS 2012]

When I try to debug, I get this error:

[image: Error]

If I change the computer name to anything else, I get this error:

[image: Other error]

Is being able to debug .Net 4.0 apps remotely from Visual Studio 2012 on Windows XP wishful thinking on my part or should this work?

Just to give some background, we have some .Net 4.0 code running on Windows 7 ok, but crashing under XP. I understand that the .Net 4.5 compiler is an in place upgrade of the 4.0 compiler, and if you have a bug in .Net 4.0 which has been fixed in 4.5, your 4.0 code will compile fine because you are using the more up to date, fixed compiler, but you may get runtime issues on actual .Net 4.0 machines. I suspect this may be the case and wish to test it out.

And we have to use Visual Studio 2012, I don't make the rules!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx) tells us (2012 Oct 8) that there is no support for remote debugging from VS 2012 to XP:

Remote Debugging
The Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 do not support remote debugging on an XP client. When debugging on Windows XP is required, it is recommended to [use the debuggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of an older version of Visual Studio, such as Visual Studio 2010, for local or remote debugging. This is in line with the Windows Vista experience for Visual Studio 2012 RTM, which is a runtime target but not a remote debugging target.

Comment: Thanks for this, a MessageBox if you tried to remote debug from 2012 to XP explaining this would have saved me a lot of time, as opposed to some ambiguous error that makes you feel as though you have got a setting wrong haha

Comment: Note the Microsoft blog post provides a link that serves as a workaround for debugging (in 2010) an application that was built using VS2012. See the link on "use the debuggers".