# Remote debugging VS2013 on a Windows Server 2003 machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2003, remote-debugging

It could be that what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible (as I can't find out how to do it!) but basically I've upgraded my VS Version from 2010 to 2013.

All of my companies test sites are running on IIS 6 on Windows 2003 Server.

And what I'm trying to do is remote debug my solutions on this machine (Which I was able to do in VS2010).

So my question is...is this possible or will I need to convince someone to upgrade the server?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: What error do you get? Did you copy VS2013 remote debugger over to the server? Each VS can work only with the same version of remote debugger.

Comment: Hi Pepo, The error that I'm receiving is that the VS2013 remote debugging software cannot install on this (Server 2003) operating system

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40781&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True) windows 2003 is not supported by remote debugger for visual studio 2013. Sorry :(

Comment: This link details why this is a problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087644/visual-studio-2013-remote-debug-process-in-windows-xp